Можно ли к компилятору mingw подключить файлы библиотек типа . lib?
Просто я узнал что для mingw существует тип .a с приставкой lib в начале. И совсем запутался.. Можете пояснить пожалуйста, почему нельзя использовать обычный .lib?

.lib - это несовместимые файлы линкера MSVC.

В каких-то редких случаях вроде можно (для некоторых чисто С-шных библиотек?), так что сам формат файла он понимает. В остальном - другой компилятор, другой формат файла, не вижу проблемы.
